# How does a Touchstone (s2p) file indicate whether it should pass or block DC?

Tags: capacitor, amplifier, inductor, simulation, impedance

I'm trying to simulate impedance matches for an [LDMOS FET amplifier](https://youtu.be/GLFeoOHoRuA) with Touchstone (s2p) files to simulate the device with "real components" before we build it.  I have found that "capacitor" s2p files leak DC current and that "inductor" s2p files don't pass as much DC as you would expect for the milliOhm specification.

- Is there something that specifies the DC charactaristics of the s2p model in the file that I could modify?
- Are there other ways to solve this?  For example, would an ideal parallel-inductor with a 1e9 nH or an ideal series-capacitor with 1e9 uF across the s2p component help with this in the simulator?
- Other thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is it doesn't. You can find the Touchstone 2.0 file specification here: http://www.ibis.org/touchstone_ver2.0/touchstone_ver2_0.pdf. There's no provision for specifying DC behaviour.

Indeed, at least one simulator I've used that supports using S-parameter files in a transient simulation where DC behaviour is important has a check box to specify whether to consider the component an open or short at DC.

I agree that if the software doesn't support that, a large ideal parallel inductor or large ideal series cap should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Touchstone files are essentially an array of scattering matrices that are indexed by frequency, which may or may not approach DC, depending how they were measured (or generated by other simulation tools).  Behaviour at frequencies not included in the recorded data are either interpolated or extrapolated (which can give some very inaccurate results!)

You mention that you are modelling an LDMOS amplifier, which are generally power amplifiers.  Unless you have power dependant s parameter data obtained from a load pull, then you are not using the right tool for the job.  Power amplifiers are not matched in the same way as small signal amplifiers - a classical conjugate match for maximum power transfer is not the correct method.  A power amplifier is matched to develop its maximum output power - usually by way of a load line derived from its DC characteristics as a starting point.  You really need to be using a non-linear (spice or volterra series) model.  S parameters are just linear sets of results for fixed bias conditions - they are just data sets and will not vary with supply voltage, for example.

If you are stuck with only linear s-parameter data - you can approximate load pull contours using the Cripps method - I refer you to  https://www.microwaves101.com/encyclopedias/cripps-analysis

Have fun!

Comment: We are using the Microwave Office high power models from NXP for the LDMOS PA.  Really this question is about the DC charectaristics of s2p models for inductors and capacitors since the DC behavior of the bias tee for the drain will affect the Ids and possibly Vds in system.  We used "DCSHORT" component to bypass inductor s2p's to make sure they are passing DC, and used 1-Farad ideal caps on either side of the capacitor s2p's so they wont pass DC in the model.  With those two additions the simulation nearly matches  NXP's reference values, whereas before we weren't even getting close.